# Solving vector equations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out how to use Mathematica to solve systems of equations where some of the variables and coefficients are vectors. A simple example would be something like

[image: A + Vt = Pt]

where I know **A**, **V**, and the magnitude of **P**, and I have to solve for *t* and the *direction* of P.  (Basically, given two rays A and B, where I know everything about A but only the origin and magnitude of B, figure out what the direction of B must be such that it intersects A.)

Now, I know how to solve this sort of thing by hand, but that's slow and error-prone, so I was hoping I could use Mathematica to speed things along and error-check me. However, I can't see how to get Mathematica to symbolically solve equations involving vectors like this.

I've looked in the VectorAnalysis package, without finding anything there that seems relevant; meanwhile the Linear Algebra package only seems to have a solver for linear systems (which this isn't, since I don't know *t* or **P**, just **|P|**).

I tried doing the simpleminded thing: expanding the vectors into their components (pretend they're 3D) and solving them as if I were trying to equate two parametric functions,

```
Solve[ 
      { Function[t, {Bx + Vx*t, By + Vy*t, Bz + Vz*t}][t] == 
          Function[t, {Px*t, Py*t, Pz*t}][t],
        Px^2 + Py^2 + Pz^2 == Q^2 } , 
      { t, Px, Py, Pz } 
     ]
```

but the "solution" that spits out is a huge mess of coefficients and congestion. It also forces me to expand out each of the dimensions I feed it.

What I want is a nice symbolic solution in terms of dot products, cross products, and norms:

[image]

But I can't see how to tell `Solve` that some of the coefficients are vectors instead of scalars.

Is this possible? Can Mathematica give me symbolic solutions on vectors? Or should I just stick with No.2 Pencil technology?

(Just to be clear, I'm not interested in the solution to the particular equation at top -- I'm asking if I can use Mathematica to solve computational geometry problems like that generally without my having to express everything as an explicit matrix of `{Ax, Ay, Az}`, etc.)

Comment: It might be worth your time to ask the Mathematica folks this question as well.  They probably know their own software better than we do.

Comment: I'll try posting to the MathGroup forums ( http://forums.wolfram.com/ ). It doesn't seem like simply mailing support@wolfram.com will provide useful results.

Comment: It's surprising, though, how often the signal to noise ratio (and just the whole system in general) is better here than in an "old-fashioned" mailing list/forum/newsgroup.

Answer (score 9):

---

With Mathematica 7.0.1.0

```
Clear[A, V, P];
A = {1, 2, 3};
V = {4, 5, 6};
P = {P1, P2, P3};
Solve[A + V t == P, P]
```

outputs:

```
{{P1 -> 1 + 4 t, P2 -> 2 + 5 t, P3 -> 3 (1 + 2 t)}}
```

Typing out P = {P1, P2, P3} can be annoying if the array or matrix is large.

```
Clear[A, V, PP, P];
A = {1, 2, 3};
V = {4, 5, 6};
PP = Array[P, 3];
Solve[A + V t == PP, PP]
```

outputs:

```
{{P[1] -> 1 + 4 t, P[2] -> 2 + 5 t, P[3] -> 3 (1 + 2 t)}}
```

Matrix vector inner product:

```
Clear[A, xx, bb];
A = {{1, 5}, {6, 7}};
xx = Array[x, 2];
bb = Array[b, 2];
Solve[A.xx == bb, xx]
```

outputs:

```
{{x[1] -> 1/23 (-7 b[1] + 5 b[2]), x[2] -> 1/23 (6 b[1] - b[2])}}
```

Matrix multiplication:

```
Clear[A, BB, d];
A = {{1, 5}, {6, 7}};
BB = Array[B, {2, 2}];
d = {{6, 7}, {8, 9}};
Solve[A.BB == d]
```

outputs:

```
{{B[1, 1] -> -(2/23), B[2, 1] -> 28/23, B[1, 2] -> -(4/23), B[2, 2] -> 33/23}}
```

The dot product has an infix notation built in just use a period for the dot.

I do not think the cross product does however. This is how you use the Notation package to make one.  "X" will become our infix form of Cross. I suggest coping the example from the Notation, Symbolize and InfixNotation tutorial. Also use the Notation Palette which helps abstract away some of the Box syntax.

```
Clear[X]
Needs["Notation`"]
Notation[x_ X y_\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]Cross[x_, y_]]
Notation[NotationTemplateTag[
  RowBox[{x_,  , X,  , y_,  }]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
  NotationTemplateTag[RowBox[{ , 
RowBox[{Cross, [, 
RowBox[{x_, ,, y_}], ]}]}]]]
{a, b, c} X {x, y, z}
```

outputs:

```
{-c y + b z, c x - a z, -b x + a y}
```

The above looks horrible but when using the Notation Palette it looks like:

```
Clear[X]
Needs["Notation`"]
Notation[x_ X y_\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]Cross[x_, y_]]
{a, b, c} X {x, y, z}
```

I have run into some quirks using the notation package in the past versions of mathematica so be careful.

Comment: In `Solve[A + V t == P, P]` you've missed the `t` multiplying `P`.

Comment: You type cross product with `:esc: cross :esc:`.

Comment: @rcollyer
My mistake, should work fine with the addition.

@KennyTM
Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a general solution for you by any means (MathForum may be the better way to go), but there are some tips that I can offer you. The first is to do the expansion of your vectors into components in a more systematic way. For instance, I would solve the equation you wrote as follows.

```
rawSol = With[{coords = {x, y, z}},
  Solve[
    Flatten[
     {A[#] + V[#] t == P[#] t & /@ coords,
     Total[P[#]^2 & /@ coords] == P^2}],
    Flatten[{t, P /@ coords}]]];
```

Then you can work with the `rawSol` variable more easily. Next, because you are referring the vector components in a uniform way (always matching the Mathematica pattern `v_[x|y|z]`), you can define rules that will aid in simplifying them. I played around a bit before coming up with the following rules:

```
vectorRules =
  {forms___ + vec_[x]^2 + vec_[y]^2 + vec_[z]^2 :> forms + vec^2,
   forms___ + c_. v1_[x]*v2_[x] + c_. v1_[y]*v2_[y] + c_. v1_[z]*v2_[z] :>
     forms + c v1\[CenterDot]v2};
```

These rules will simplify the relationships for vector norms and dot products (cross-products are left as a likely painful exercise for the reader). **EDIT:** rcollyer pointed out that you can make `c` optional in the rule for dot products, so you only need two rules for norms and dot products.

With these rules, I was immediately able to simplify the solution for `t` into a form very close to yours:

```
  In[3] := t /. rawSol //. vectorRules // Simplify // InputForm
  Out[3] = {(A \[CenterDot] V - Sqrt[A^2*(P^2 - V^2) + 
                                   (A \[CenterDot] V)^2])/(P^2 - V^2), 
            (A \[CenterDot] V + Sqrt[A^2*(P^2 - V^2) + 
                                   (A \[CenterDot] V)^2])/(P^2 - V^2)}
```

Like I said, it's not a complete way of solving these kinds of problems by any means, but if you're careful about casting the problem into terms that are easy to work with from a pattern-matching and rule-replacement standpoint, you can go pretty far.

Comment: The two dot-product rules can be merged into one by replacing the `c_` in the first rule with `c_.` or `c:1`, where the period tells Mathematica to use the standard default for multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a somewhat different approach to this issue.  I've made some definitions that return this output:
[image: vExpand examples]
Patterns that are known to be vector quantities may be specified using `vec[_]`, patterns that have an `OverVector[]` or `OverHat[]` wrapper (symbols with a vector or hat over them) are assumed to be vectors by default.

The definitions are experimental and should be treated as such, but they seem to work well.  I expect to add to this over time.

Here are the definitions.  The need to be pasted into a Mathematica Notebook cell and converted to StandardForm to see them properly.

```
Unprotect[vExpand,vExpand$,Cross,Plus,Times,CenterDot];

(* vec[pat] determines if pat is a vector quantity.
vec[pat] can be used to define patterns that should be treated as vectors.
Default: Patterns are assumed to be scalar unless otherwise defined *)
vec[_]:=False;

(* Symbols with a vector hat, or vector operations on vectors are assumed to be vectors *)
vec[OverVector[_]]:=True;
vec[OverHat[_]]:=True;

vec[u_?vec+v_?vec]:=True;
vec[u_?vec-v_?vec]:=True;
vec[u_?vec\[Cross]v_?vec]:=True;
vec[u_?VectorQ]:=True;

(* Placeholder for matrix types *)
mat[a_]:=False;

(* Anything not defined as a vector or matrix is a scalar *)
scal[x_]:=!(vec[x]\[Or]mat[x]);
scal[x_?scal+y_?scal]:=True;scal[x_?scal y_?scal]:=True;

(* Scalars times vectors are vectors *)
vec[a_?scal u_?vec]:=True;
mat[a_?scal m_?mat]:=True;

vExpand$[u_?vec\[Cross](v_?vec+w_?vec)]:=vExpand$[u\[Cross]v]+vExpand$[u\[Cross]w];
vExpand$[(u_?vec+v_?vec)\[Cross]w_?vec]:=vExpand$[u\[Cross]w]+vExpand$[v\[Cross]w];
vExpand$[u_?vec\[CenterDot](v_?vec+w_?vec)]:=vExpand$[u\[CenterDot]v]+vExpand$[u\[CenterDot]w];
vExpand$[(u_?vec+v_?vec)\[CenterDot]w_?vec]:=vExpand$[u\[CenterDot]w]+vExpand$[v\[CenterDot]w];

vExpand$[s_?scal (u_?vec\[Cross]v_?vec)]:=Expand[s] vExpand$[u\[Cross]v];
vExpand$[s_?scal (u_?vec\[CenterDot]v_?vec)]:=Expand[s] vExpand$[u\[CenterDot]v];

vExpand$[Plus[x__]]:=vExpand$/@Plus[x];
vExpand$[s_?scal,Plus[x__]]:=Expand[s](vExpand$/@Plus[x]);
vExpand$[Times[x__]]:=vExpand$/@Times[x];

vExpand[e_]:=e//.e:>Expand[vExpand$[e]]

(* Some simplification rules *)
(u_?vec\[Cross]u_?vec):=\!\(\*OverscriptBox["0", "\[RightVector]"]\);
(u_?vec+\!\(\*OverscriptBox["0", "\[RightVector]"]\)):=u;
0v_?vec:=\!\(\*OverscriptBox["0", "\[RightVector]"]\);

\!\(\*OverscriptBox["0", "\[RightVector]"]\)\[CenterDot]v_?vec:=0;
v_?vec\[CenterDot]\!\(\*OverscriptBox["0", "\[RightVector]"]\):=0;

(a_?scal u_?vec)\[Cross]v_?vec :=a u\[Cross]v;u_?vec\[Cross](a_?scal v_?vec ):=a u\[Cross]v;
(a_?scal u_?vec)\[CenterDot]v_?vec :=a u\[CenterDot]v;
u_?vec\[CenterDot](a_?scal v_?vec) :=a u\[CenterDot]v;

(* Stealing behavior from Dot *)
Attributes[CenterDot]=Attributes[Dot];

Protect[vExpand,vExpand$,Cross,Plus,Times,CenterDot];
```